# django-cors-headers dont work with DRF(Django Rest Framework)

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, python-3.6, django-cors-headers

I'm trying to add [django-cors-headers](https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers) to my django rest API to add the HTTP header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in the response object, but I have not managed to make it work. I have followed the instructions in the official documentation but I can not get it to work.

## Here is the content of my `settings.py` file:

`...
    INSTALLED_APPS = [
        'suit',
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
        'rest_framework',
        'corsheaders',
        'hvad',
        'rest_framework.authtoken',
        'rest_framework_swagger',
        'accounts.apps.AccountsConfig',
        'rest_auth',
    ]
    ...
    MIDDLEWARE:[
        'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
        ...
    ]
    ...
    # CORS Config
    CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
    CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = False`

## I'm using:

- Django 1.11.14
- django-cors-headers 2.4.0
- djangorestframework 3.8.2
- python 3.6.5
- pip 10.0.1
- Windows 10

Comment: Your question is not clear. What is the error? What is the problem?

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear. I am trying to use the django-cors-headers package to add some HTTP headers in the Reponse object of my REST API, the official DRF documentation recommends the use of this package to deal with the CORS here is the [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/ajax-csrf-cors/#cors)

Comment: What is the error you are getting that is making you believe that it is not working?

Comment: I do not get any errors, just that my django-cors-headers does not add the HTTP header Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Comment: Finally It works only when I create a new middleware file, here's the file https://gist.github.com/fronzec/9098d57e3f1b36aeabd5c4927eafa90f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally. It only works when I create a new middleware file. Here's the content of my middleware:

1. Put this file under `<your_app>/middleware/cors.py`
2. Edit your `setting.py` to add the new middleware

   ```py
    # -*- coding:utf-8 -*-

    from django.http import HttpResponse
    from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin

    class CorsMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
        def process_response(self, request, response):
            response["Acces-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*"
            return response
   ```

Answer (score 1):

If you are Using Chrome, Use 
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en

================================================================================

```
CORS_URLS_REGEX = r'^/*$'
```

CORS_ALLOW_METHODS

A list of HTTP verbs that are allowed for the actual request. Defaults to:

```
CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = (
    'DELETE',
    'GET',
    'OPTIONS',
    'PATCH',
    'POST',
    'PUT',
)

CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = (
    'accept',
    'accept-encoding',
    'authorization',
    'content-type',
    'dnt',
    'origin',
    'user-agent',
    'x-csrftoken',
    'x-requested-with',
)
```

Answer (score 0):

`django-cors-headers` is reasonably fool-proof and your configuration seems correct to me.

There is however a gotcha I've had issues with too: 
If you configure your server to serve static files without invoking Django / Python (pretty common, even on the built-in server), `django-cors-headers` cannot apply a CORS header to those responses.
Depending on the browser, this will cause problems with asynchronous requests, fonts and sometimes even images, video and audio.

[More info on CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)